# Can't see the output on root React Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've installed the web pack already, and everything is working fine.

When I run `webpack-dev-server --progress --color --watch`

it runs correctly, but when accessing the port `localhost:8080`, it shows `Hello Webpack` which is an output from ./src/bundle.js.

But when I open `localhost:8080/bundle` it outputs what I want, which is the `entry.js` output.

**My index.html**

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>My first React</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root-app"></div>
    <script src="./src/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My entry.js**

```
import "./style.css";

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

document.write ("I'm working fine");
```

What do I have wrong to output "entry.js" instead of "./src/bundle.js" correctly on the root when accessing my port 8080.

EDIT: **My webpack.config.js**

```
    module.exports = {
  entry: "./entry.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
  rules: [
  { 
    test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
   },
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env', 'react', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: [require('babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread', 'trasnform-runtime')]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
};
```

Comment: webpack.config.js file code please?

Comment: @Aaqib Already added as an edit.

Comment: What local server do you use?